# lme4 bar specification for random effects

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

Wondering if anyone can simply state in which case I should specify either `||` or `|` in my lmer model? 
Am I right in thinking a rule of thumb would be that it is okay to use `||` in the case of low covariance of my variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an *in press* paper by [Bates et al](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf).:

```
x+(x|g)   1+x+(1+x|g)        Correlated random intercept and slope
x+(x||g)  1+x+(1|g)+(0+x|g)  Uncorrelated random intercept and slope
```

So you use `||` want you want your random intercept and random slope effects to be uncorrelated. So the rule of thumb is: use `|` (correlated terms) unless you know what you are doing and there is a reason why you want to model your variables as uncorrelated. It is not simply "low covariance" since you model those effects as random, on different levels, so it is not the same as lowest level correlation or covariance.

Comment: Also see the next paragraph of that paper: `The use
of models [using ||] should ideally be restricted to cases where the predictor is measured on a ratio scale (i.e., the zero point on the scale is meaningful, not just a location defined by convenience or convention), as is the case here."

Comment: Is the intuition: "My model variables will probably have totally different (uncorrelated) random effects" ?

Comment: Not different - rather uncorrelated (independent), and not probably - you declare in your model definition that they are uncorrelated.